# C# and Lotus notes attachment icon

Tags: c#, icons, lotus-notes, attachment

I am using C# and need to attach a lnk (shortcut/link) file and email it to a lotus notes account. The problem is the icon defaults to a generic image and does not show the folder with the arrow as seen in Windows Explorer. A txt file icon does display as expected. I would like to control the appearance of that icon after it has been received. Can this be done through C# or is the Notes server the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you are asking how to control the appearance of the icon once it arrives in the recipient's mail.

I do remember (from when we were on Notes here at work) that the icon was specific to the *sender* as opposed to the recipient (i.e. if I send you a Word document and I have Word 97 installed and you have 2003 installed, you'll see the Word 97 doc icon).  But this appeared to be a function of the fact that I, the sender, was using Notes as the sending client.  However, I think you may not be able to do what you want to do as one would assume you are sending regular SMTP e-mail.  Assuming you are sending e-mail through the Notes server's SMTP interface, I don't believe you'll be able to control how the link appears on the recipient's side.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I suspected as much, but still had hope :)